# PC as Bluetooth speakers

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I know that:

- There are Bluetooth speakers for my phone and for my iPod
- My desktop computer has Bluetooth dongle
- My desktop has speakers attached to it;)

So, my question is: can I use my desktop PC as Bluetooth speakers for my iPod/mobile phone, preferably using Linux?

Comment: Just to note, I managed to do this on windows with Widcomm 6.2 and 6.4. Hopefully, we'll see this in BlueZ soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically yes, although the necessary support is not yet complete/available.

[link](http://www.mail-archive.com/pulseaudio-discuss@mail.0pointer.de/msg04540.html)

[link](http://www.mail-archive.com/pulseaudio-discuss@mail.0pointer.de/msg05754.html)

[link](http://www.mail-archive.com/pulseaudio-discuss@mail.0pointer.de/msg06187.html)

Comment: More details about the links would be nice.

Comment: Meh. The links themselves are not interesting enough to warrant descriptions. They're just threads in the PulseAudio mailing list regarding getting BlueZ working as a source.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can
http://bluetooth-alsa.sourceforge.net/
this project contain utility a2recv which act as a2dp headset and plays sound trough soundcard